# How can I tell if a string only contains letter AND spaces

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having trouble figuring out the above question and have a felling I should be testing every character with "for character in string" however I cant really figure out how that would work

This is what I have now but I know it doesnt work as intended because it only allows me to test letters but I also need to know spaces so for example " MY dear aunt sally" should say yes contains only letters and spaces

```
    #Find if string only contains letters and spaces
    if string.isalpha():
      print("Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes")
    else:
      print("Only alphabetic letters and spaces: no")
```

Comment: did you want the function to return true for `foo` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a *generator expression* within [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in function :

```
if all(i.isalpha() or i.isspace() for i in my_string)
```

But note that `i.isspace()` will check if the character is a whitespace if you just want `space` you can directly compare with space :

```
if all(i.isalpha() or i==' ' for i in my_string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i==' ' for i in 'test string')
True
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i==' ' for i in 'test    string') #delimiter is tab
False
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i==' ' for i in 'test#string')
False
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i.isspace() for i in 'test string')
True
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i.isspace() for i in 'test       string')
True
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i.isspace() for i in 'test@string')
False
```

Comment: but it returns true for `teststring` , i think op wants to return false.

Comment: @AvinashRaj mmm, i don't think so as i cant see such thing in question, any way i need to wait for OP's response!

Answer (score 1):

just another way for Fun, I know its not that good:

```
>>> a
'hello baby'
>>> b
'hello1 baby'
>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z ]",a)==list(a)  # return True if string is only alpha and space
True
>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z ]",b)==list(b) # returns False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Cascade `replace` with `isalpha`:

```
'a b'.replace(' ', '').isalpha() # True
```

`replace` returns a copy of the original string with everything but the spaces. Then you can use `isalpha` on that return value (since the return value is a string itself) to test if it only contains alphabet characters.

To match all whitespace, you're probably going to want to use Kasra's answer, but just for completeness, I'll demonstrate using `re.sub` with a whitespace character class:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\s', '', 'a b').isalpha()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below `re.match` fucntion would return a match object only if the input contain alphabets or spaces.

```
>>> re.match(r'[A-Za-z ]+$', 'test string')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='test string'>
>>> re.match(r'(?=.*? )[A-Za-z ]+$', 'test@bar')
>>>
```